# Difference between pointers when malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I usually make myself a struct and I allocate memory for the struct and sometimes for buffers inside the struct. Like so:

```
typedef struct A
{
  char *buffer;
  int size;
} A;
```

Then when I malloc for the struct I do this. (I learned not to cast the malloc return here on SO.)

*X*

```
A *a = malloc(sizeof(a));
a->buffer = malloc(10*sizeof(a->buffer));
```

**What is the difference between X and Y this?**

*Y*

```
 A *a = malloc(sizeof(*a));
 a->buffer = malloc(10*sizeof(a->buffer));
```

They seem to be doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm supposing your `buffer` pointer points to an arbitrary amount of data? It's not clear from your code snippet. In that case, `a->buffer = malloc(sizeof(a->buffer)` is wrong since it will always only allocate 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending upon whether you are on a 32-bit or 64 bit machine.

Comment: The difference is that `sizeof(a*)` is a syntax error whereas `sizeof(a)` is more subtly wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to allocate 10 times the size of a buffer pointer for our buffer?

Comment: I want to allocate space for 10 characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither is correct, the second one doesn't even compile.

You want either of these:

```
A * a = malloc(sizeof(A));    // repeat the type

// or:

A * a = malloc(sizeof *a);    // be smart
```

Then:

```
a->size = 213;
a->buffer = malloc(a->size);
```

Comment: `a->buffer = malloc(a->size);` Will the compiler know to do `size * character size`?

Comment: @MikeJohn: `sizeof(char)` is one, by definition. Generally, though, you'll have to multiply by the size of the type, indeed.

Comment: Although I added `10` * sizeof... in an edit why do you say the second doesn't compile?

Comment: Anyway, what I learned from you is that it should be with the pointer. `malloc(sizeof *a);`   Thanks.

Comment: @MikeJohn: The question was edited, so that's not a fair use of time. It originally said `sizeof(a*)`, which isn't valid C. Never mind.

Comment: @MikeJohn: Well, I would phrase this as "Use `sizeof` with an *expression*, not a *type*." The asterisk denoted dereference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you should typecast it (A *) because calloc or malloc return void *.

```
A *a=(a*)malloc(sizeof(A));
```

suppose you want to allocate memory for buffer for 10 characters

```
a->buffer=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```